# How can golang gin get the array parameters of GET requests query string?

Tags: go, go-gin

I am using gin to implement the original PHP API. Currently, there are online requests similar to

`/path?a[]=1&a[]=2&b[0]=1&b[1]=2&c[0][age]=1&c[0][name]=abc`.

How can I get such array parameters in gin?

get value like:

```
a=["1", "2"]
b=["1", "2"]
c=[{"age": "1", "name": "abc"}]
```

It seems that gin does not support this parameter. Is there any elegant way to get such  parameters?

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [Pull Request](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/pull/570) on github,I found a possible solution to get the parameters like `a[]=1&a[]=2`:

[image]

Code in golang:

```golang
// Return an array
a, _ := ctx.GetQueryArray("a[]") // Or just use QueryArray("a[]") directly.
ctx.JSON(200, gin.H{
    "a[]": a,
})
```

Parameters like `&b[0]=1&b[1]=2`, You could use `QueryMap` directly(This wouldn't return an array,though):

[image]

```golang
// Return a map.
ctx.JSON(200, gin.H{
    "b": ctx.QueryMap("b"),
})
```

I don't think there is a direct way to get an array with map.I did some changes from the source code of `get` in `gin.Context`(hardcode):

```
var dicts []map[string]string
key := "a"
queryMap := ctx.Request.URL.Query()
//log.Println(dicts) // dicts[0] except
for k, v := range queryMap {
    if i:= strings.IndexByte(k, '['); i >= 1 && k[0:i] == key{
        if j := strings.IndexByte(k[i+1:], ']'); j >= 1{
            index, _ := strconv.Atoi(k[i+1: i+j+1]) // get the index of slice
            if index > len(dicts){
                ctx.JSON(200, gin.H{
                    "403": "Check your data",
                })
                return
            }
            if index == len(dicts){
                tmp := make(map[string]string)
                dicts = append(dicts, tmp)
            }
            pre :=strings.IndexByte(k[i+j+2:], '[')
            last:=strings.IndexByte(k[i+j+2:], ']')
            dicts[index][k[i+j+3+pre: i+j+2+last]] = v[0]
        }
    }
}
ctx.JSON(200, gin.H{
    "a": dicts,
})
```

Example:
[image]
When data out of bounds:
[image]